# Processing strange file format C++

Tags: c++, audio, hex, ascii

I'm trying to read in a .wac file, and there is little on this on the Internet. I have read the file into a Hex editor and get the following output:

[image]

Basically, I know the first part of the file contains the word "WAac" but then contains some weird encoding and in some parts hex after the file being has read in I get the following "Unprintable" I just do not know where to go from here, in terms of reading the rest of the header file, and, the data because there is no information out there regarding the format. My code is as follows:

```
    struct s_wac_hdr 
    {   
         char id[4];
         uint32_t size; 
         char type[4];
    };

      s_wac_hdr wac_hdr;
  s_chunk_hdr chunk_hdr;

  std::vector<uint8_t> fmt_data;

  file.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&wac_hdr), sizeof(wac_hdr));

  std::cout << "Header Id: " << wac_hdr.id << std::endl; 

  std::cout << "Header Type: " << wac_hdr.type << std::endl;
```

Any help regarding this would be greatly appreciated because I do not not have a clue to where I am going.

Comment: Observation: the repeated XX XX XX 00 YY YY YY 00 pattern, with the third nonzero byte (visually appearing) less likely to be large than the other two, suggests 32-bit little-endian binary numbers to me.

Comment: @Zack Hey Zack, thanks :) So is this file therefore readable? I cannot find anything on the Internet..

Comment: Sorry, "I think those might be 32-bit little-endian numbers there" is all I've got for you.  It looks like you have a nice little reverse engineering challenge for yourself :-/

Comment: @Zack I feel so dumb right now. :( I don't know why this person has used this file format.. It seems really strange that they would, instead of using .wav (it would make my life so much simpler) If there was a resource online where the format was printed then it would be a lot more easier. Wish me luck ha

Comment: Waac (or .wac) is an audio file format used by the bioware infinity game engine, now I have no insight in the file format itself, but maybe bioware will respond to an inquiry (although I highly doubt it).

Comment: @ArneKjetilAndersen No, it's not though.. That's the thing.. I investigated further and what's on sites such as 'http://filext.com/' is wrong since on here: http://extension.informer.com/wac Omnipeek have released they own the format.

Comment: @Phorce But the omnipeek thing is not audio - that is a network analyzer something - I might be misunderstanding, but I know for a fact that wac is a audio format from bioware, but yeah - finding information about wac is really hard, I found a converter for wac->wav, but the download link did not work - so I'm afraid I cannot do more, sorry!

Comment: @ArneKjetilAndersen No problem :) What would you therefore suggest I do? It seems that this problem AFAIK cannot be solved.. Since the file information is not published

Comment: @Phorce If I understand you correctly, this is an audio file - right? Do you know what the audio should sound like or do you have a wav-file of the same? As far as I understand wac audio i merely a wav-file with a custom header (I might be wrong - but that is what I've gathered so far) - Now i would start by trying to write the payload of the file (beyond the header), and put various wav-headers in front - but again - speculation on my side...

Comment: @ArneKjetilAndersen Hey, yes, I kind of know but could acquire what software he uses.. But, I tried using 'sox' but just got the fact that a sample rate is not given for the file.. Mhm, do you think applying a different/additional header might help?

Comment: This is all a wild goose chase, but if you have no choice, you have to go down that road. Now my idea would be to take the payload of the file (all data beyond the header), stick various wav-headers in front of that and try to play the audio to see if it sounded like something correct. Now the sample rate should not be a problem, if that is wrong, then the audio would sound like chipmunks or like slow and deep - then you'd just adjust SR until it sounded good - not sure this will lead you to the solution though.

Comment: @ArneKjetilAndersen But, how would I get hold of the data sorry? I can't read past the header in order to get to the data... I get your idea, and, it does sound logical; just don't know how I would go about something like this